# Problem with Axios moving from localhost to AWS Amplify

Tags: javascript

I am running a web app locally that uses Axios and all is working well. I am now trying to deploy the app to AWS Amplify.

I am getting a 404 error on the same Axios post that works with localhost.

What do I need to configure for the app to work when deployed? And if possible can I configure it to work locally when running on my machine and remotely when deployed?

Here's the code:

```js
async function submit() {
    const bizCard = {
        name: document.getElementById("name").value,
        title: document.getElementById("title").value,
        org: document.getElementById("organization").value,
        phone: document.getElementById("phone").value,
        email: document.getElementById("email").value
    }
    console.log(bizCard)
    openModal();
    hideQRCode();
    showSpinner();
    axios.post('/api/issue', bizCard).then((response) => {
        let inviteURL = "https://web.cloud.streetcred.id/link/?c_i=" + response.data.invitation;
        setQRCodeImage(inviteURL);
        hideSpinner();
        showQRCode();
    });
}
```

Comment: What type of application are you using? use any framework? how are you exposing the routes? did you open the port in AWS to allow request to your app? Your code is for the client-side, but where is running your API?

Comment: Did you checked your baseURL?

Comment: Thanks @YoandryCollazo I have not configured AWS to allow the port I am using. I'll look into that.

Comment: Thanks @CharukaHS actually I an not giving any value to baseURL which I imagine is taking localhost as default value. Should I set the baseURL to the URL of where my app is running?

Comment: @Matthieu only with that piece of code I cannot pinpoint this is what you are doing wrong. I would like to suggest first make sure yourdomain.com/api/issue exist, if your backend and frontend are accessed by different domains it can cause this kind of issue.

Comment: Plus there are some security parameters that should enable manually to get access. Worth checking those settings too

Comment: Thanks @CharukaHS so now what is happening is that the POST to yourdomain.com/api/issue does not fail but times out. So there's progress I guess. It uses port 3000 as default and my guess is that this port is disabled or not configured properly in AWS Amplify. So I am kinda stuck. Any idea?

Comment: I dont have much experience in aws either. And still I don't know what frameworks you are using for frontend / backend. So I think you should follow some tutorial like [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-dynamodb-tutorial.html)